# Changing Bounding Box Label Format

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box

I was looking for an online service that allow me to annotate images with bounding boxes, I found [labelbox](https://labelbox.com/), but there bounding box label format is different than the format that I need which is yolo.

This is there format: `"bbox": { "top": 186, "left": 192,  "height": 300, "width": 519 }`.

The format that i need is `x_center y_center width height`, also the values needs to be between 0 and 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bbox = {"top": 186, "left": 192,  "height": 300, "width": 519}

y1 = bbox["top"]
x1 = bbox["left"]
height = bbox["height"]
width = bbox["width"]

x2 = x1+width
y2 = y1+height

x_center = round((x1+x2)/2)
y_center = round((y1+y2)/2)

bbox_list = [x_center, y_center, width, height]
```

Comment: @Mohammed Aljahdali If solution helps, can you accept it as a solution?